# Finding the library versions a library was linked against

Tags: ubuntu, libraries

I have a library that was compiled on an unknown Ubuntu machine, And I'd like to determine what version of Ubuntu that machine had at the compile time.

My idea was to try and find the versions of different libraries used (e.g. the kernel), knowing that these versions changed with different releases. Iv'e tried using `nm` and `ldd`, but I can't seem to find any relevant info.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe

```
 readelf -a
```

It displays information about ELF files. If the object you are studying still contains the comment section, you may try to extract it by

```
 readelf -p .comment yourfile
```

For example

```
$ cat test.c
int main () {
  return 0;
}
$ gcc test.c
$ readelf -p .comment a.out

String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
```

`objdump` could provide the same information.

If the comment section is stripped, you may try to read the GCC runtime symbol version info from the  `readelf -a` command if it is a c++ compiled library. Note, that is the version of symbols supplied to the compiler and not necessarily the version of the compiler. I don't know how useful that would be to track down the Ubuntu version.

Comment: Nope.. It doesn't look promising:
 OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
 ABI Version:                       0

Comment: Could you explain how you you go about doing this? Iv'e gone through the readelf output, and haven't found anything useful. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the answer to contain an example.